# adding function to Drupal.behaviors

Tags: php, javascript, drupal

I'm developing a Drupal module. I need to set the focus to the first form element when a page is loaded. I read this can be done by using the jquery code -`$('#edit-name').focus();`.

How do I add this code to the Drupal.behaviors so that my code will be automatically called when the page is loaded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a example on how to use behaviors: [Drupal.behaviors](http://mydrupalblog.lhmdesign.com/drupal-theming-jquery-basics-inc-drupal-behaviors).

So all you need to do is put this in a .js file  (or add it with inline):
For Drupal6:

```
Drupal.behaviors.focus = function (context) {
    $('#edit-name').focus();
};
```

For Drupal7:

```
(function($) {
   Drupal.behaviors.focus = {
       attach:function(context,settings) {
           $('#edit-name').focus();
    }
   }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You sir are my "Today's hero of the internet"

Answer (score 1):

`drupal_add_js("$('#edit-name').focus();", "inline");` in module. In theme it's depend where did you want this script, possible just adding in page-XXX.tpl.php direct code of script. In template.php in preprocessors you can use above code.